# Accessing has_one object across multiple associations/join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a question about reaching across multiple association levels, if anyone could help me out?

I have a warehouse, and I'm trying to call up an inventory of products by their tag numbers. So far I can through and use methods defined in the Tag model, and grab associated Product name attributes easily enough:

```
#Warehouse.rb

has_many :tags, as: :location
has_many :products, through: :tags

#Tag.rb

belongs_to product #

  #polymorphic
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :location, polymorphic: true
```

Now when I try to get the primary category of that inventory item (`belongs_to :product`), I keep running into issues; I want to define the category in my iterative inventory list, and have the option to sort/group by it:

```
#Product.rb

  has_one :primary_category_assignment

  has_many :rfid_tags, as: :trackable
```

Each product is assigned to a category - associations are warehouses > tags > products > category_assignment > category. I'm trying to drill down to the level of the last two.

```
#CategoryAssignment.rb #this is a join table
  belongs_to :product, required: true
  belongs_to :category, required: true

#Category.rb
  has_many :products, through: :category_assignment
```

Here's some of the accompanying code I'm using to get this set up:

```
#warehouse_controller.rb

def index
    @tags = @warehouse.tags.all.joins(:ancestor_product) 
end

#warehouses/index.html.erb 

    <p><% @tags.each do |tag| %>
      tag: <%= tag.number %>, 
      location_id <%= tag.location_id %>,
      <%= tag.product.name %>, 
      Purchased at $<%= tag.product.purchase_price %></p> #grabs an attribute from the product level
      #Next level would reach through the category assignment join table (category_id) to grab the category, or at least order by the category assignment
```

Schema below for reference:

```
 #schema

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                    null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.integer  "position"
  end

  add_index "categories", ["position"], name: "index_categories_on_position", using: :btree

  create_table "category_assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
    t.boolean  "primary",     default: false
  end

    create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                                null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.float    "purchase_price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "purchase_date"
  end

  add_index "category_assignments", ["category_id"], name: "index_category_assignments_on_category_id", using: :btree
  add_index "category_assignments", ["product_id"], name: "index_category_assignments_on_product_id", using: :btree

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "number",                              null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "location_type"
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"    
  end

  add_index "tags", ["product_id"], name: "index_rfid_tags_on_ancestor_product_id", using: :btree
  add_index "tags", ["location_id"], name: "index_tags_on_location_id", using: :btree
  add_index "tags", ["location_type"], name: "index_tags_on_location_type", using: :btree
  add_index "tags", ["trackable_id"], name: "index_tags_on_trackable_id", using: :btree
  add_index "tags", ["trackable_type"], name: "index_tags_on_trackable_type", using: :btree
  add_index "tags", ["user_id"], name: "index_tags_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "warehouses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                           null: false
  end
```

Comment: Can you please edit this and write it as actual code? Use `class Product` instead of #Product.rb and indent the code properly. As is its really hard to read.

Comment: Oh - I'm just trying to show which model file belongs to each set of association, it's a rails project.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but if you write it as a minimal code example its much easier to follow.

Comment: fixed - I believe the line you're looking at was actually a comment to show the association intent for the following line.

Comment: Edited to make the flow easier to follow